# Custom wordpress submenu

Tags: menus, walker

how i can make custom wordpress menu structure via Walker?
I have current structure html structure:

```
<ul class="menu">
        <li class="active"><a href="">Item 1 </a></li>
        <li><a href="">Item 2  </a>
            <div class="walker">
                <ul>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">
                            <div class="icon">
                                <img src="images/icon_was3.png" alt="">
                            </div>
                            <div class="clearfix"></div>
                                <span>Item 21 </span>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">
                            <div class="icon">
                                <img src="images/icon_was3.png" alt="">
                            </div>
                            <div class="clearfix"></div>
                                <span>Item 22 </span>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">
                            <div class="icon">
                                <img src="images/icon_was3.png" alt="">
                            </div>
                            <div class="clearfix"></div>
                                <span>Item 23 </span>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li><a href="visual.html">Item 3  </a></li>
        <li><a href="">Item 4  </a></li>
        <li><a href="">Item 5  </a></li>
</ul>
```

How i can via class Walker make this menu? Can you help?

Comment: Is it the same icon over and over? or does the icon need to change based on something?

Comment: What are the relations between Item 2 and Item 21? What are these items? Posts? Pages? CPTs? Nav Menu items? Please edit your question adding the important information instead of useless HTML.

Comment: Item 2 - this pages, Item 21 and Item 22 - sub pages in menus

Comment: socki03 icon need change in wp-admin, but icon i can use how menu description, and via fontawesome)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

via walker class - problem is solve